# get difference between IQueryable sets

Tags: .net, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have a table with three columns. Two columns make up the PK. The table stores info about files in a directory.

I have a directory of files as my input.

The goal is get a list of the files that are added and the ones that are removed.

I have the following code:

```
string uri = "ftp://ftp.myftpsite.com/files";
FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
using (myEntities context = new myEntities())
{
    IQueryable<ITEM> storedItems = from item in context.ITEMs where item.YEAR == "2013" select item;
    List<ITEM> currentItemList = new List<ITEM>();

    string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
    while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) && line.EndsWith(".htm"))
    {
        ITEM item = new ITEM();
        item.YEAR = line.Substring(0,4);
        item.NUM = line.Substring(7,5);
        currentItemList.Add(item);                  
        line = streamReader.ReadLine();
    }

    IQueryable<ITEM> currentItems = currentItemList.AsQueryable<ITEM>();

    IQueryable<ITEM> newItems = from item in currentItems where !(from storedItem in storedItems select storedItem.YEAR + storedItem.NUM).Contains(item.YEAR + item.NUM) select item;
    IQueryable<ITEMS> removedItems = from item in storedItems where !(from currentItem in currentItems select currentItem.YEAR + currentItem.NUM).Contains(item.YEAR + item.NUM) select item;
    List<ITEM> newItemsList = newItems.ToList();
    List<ITEM> removedItemsList = removedItems.ToList();
}
```

In the end `newItems` should be the items on the ftp site and not the database and `removedItems` should be the items in the database and not on the ftp site.

The `newItems` works, but the following line returns an error:
`List<ITEM> removedItemsList = removedItems.ToList();`

The error is:

> System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of
>   type 'MYProject.ITEM'. Only primitive types or enumeration
>   types are supported in this context.

Something is wrong with my second LINQ query I think, but I'm not sure what.

Also, performance is important, so suggestions around performance are welcome.

**Current Solution:**

```
List<string> criteria = (from item in currentItemList select item.YEAR + item.NUM).ToList();
foreach(AMENDMENT a in storedItems)
{
    if(!criteria.Contains(a.YEAR + a.NUM))
        //do stuff here
}
```

So basically instead of doing the conditional statement in LINQ I did it in the if statement in a for loop. I honestly think it is quite ugly, however it has two benefits.

1. It works
2. Instead fo taking around 3 seconds like the LINQ queries were, it takes a few hundredths of a second.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Why does it work for the newItems query and not the removedItems query? They are essentially the same query?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try projecting first? If your data size isn't too extreme, it won't kill you. Otherwise you will need to get more creative.

```
IQueryable<ITEMS> removedItems = from item in storedItems.ToList() where !(from currentItem in currentItems select currentItem.YEAR + currentItem.NUM).Contains(item.YEAR + item.NUM) select item;
```

Your query is odd though. Another way might work, but I didn't vet it. You subset by 2013 already, so this just does same.

```
List<int> itemNumbers =  currentItems.Where(x=>x.YEAR ==2013).Select(x=>x.NUM).ToList();
IQueryable<ITEMS> removedItems = from item in storedItems where !itemNumbers.Contains(item.NUM) select item;
```

Comment: The only difference I see in your answer is that you added `ToList()` to the storedItems object in the LINQ query. Doing this gives me the error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MYProject.ITEM>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<MYProject.ITEM>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)` Is there something about your answer I'm missing?

Comment: I think the second answer could work, but only because it's now limited to one field we are checking against. I would prefer to have a solution that didn't have this limitation. For example, if I wasn't only concerned about 2013.

Comment: OK, I could just say `LIST<string> itemIds = from x in currentItems select x.YEAR + x.NUM` and then use the snippet: `!itemIds.Contains(item.YEAR + item.NUM)` so your solution would work for using multiple fields to compare

Comment: However, it does seem like there should be a cleaner way to do this, something like the MERGE statement in SQL.

Comment: Upon further testing, your second solution generates the same error as your first solution

Comment: The reason I was using ToList is to force a projection and get you out of the EF Linq process. The reason one works and the other doesn't is most likely due to the EF limitations on only working with primitives unless you write special EF linq extensions. EF ca be a real PITA that way. Simply put, if you project into a straight list, then scan said list using the same syntax as you did above, then it should work fine. If I have time later, I will shove it in a compiler and try and proof it. Was just trying to give you a path that would get you going.

Comment: `"The reason one works and the other doesn't is most likely due to the EF limitations on only working with primitives"` - However, in my original example the lines `IQueryable<ITEM> newItem = ` and `IQueryable<ITEMS> removedItems` do linq expressions with IQuerable objects of the same type. They essentually do the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
using (myEntities context = new myEntities())
{
    List<ITEM> storedItems = (
        from item in context.ITEMs 
        where item.YEAR == "2013" 
        select item ).ToList();

    List<ITEM> currentItemList = new List<ITEM>();

    string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
    while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) && line.EndsWith(".htm"))
    {
        ITEM item = new ITEM();
        item.YEAR = line.Substring(0,4);
        item.NUM = line.Substring(7,5);
        currentItemList.Add(item);                  
        line = streamReader.ReadLine();
    }

    List<ITEM> newItemsList = (
        from cItem in currentItems
        join sItem in storedItems
            on ( cItem.YEAR + cItem.NUM ) equals ( sItem.YEAR + sItem.NUM )
            into g
        from gItem in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where gItem == null
        select cItem ).ToList();

    List<ITEM> removedItemsList = (
        from sItem in storedItems
        join cItem in currentItems
            on ( sItem.YEAR + sItem.NUM ) equals ( cItem.YEAR + cItem.NUM )
            into g
        from gItem in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where gItem == null
        select sItem ).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Would `on (sItem.YEAR + sItem.NUM) equals (cItem.YEAR + cITEM.NUM)` be the same as `on sItem.YEAR equals cItem.YEAR && sIteam.NUM equals cItem.NUM` or am I missing something?

Comment: Aparently I was missing something. LINQ hates us and wont let us join on two fields lol :)

Answer (score 0):

**Current Solution:**

```
List<string> criteria = (from item in currentItemList select item.YEAR + item.NUM).ToList();
foreach(AMENDMENT a in storedItems)
{
    if(!criteria.Contains(a.YEAR + a.NUM))
        //do stuff here
}
```

So basically instead of doing the conditional statement in LINQ I did it in the if statement in a for loop. I honestly think it is quite ugly, however it has two benefits.

1. It works
2. Instead fo taking around 3 seconds like the LINQ queries were, it takes a few hundredths of a second.

If others have suggestions however, I'm still open to ideas.